# Can't parse all the next page links from a website using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to get all the links traversing next pages from [this website](https://www.icab.es/?go=eaf9d1a0ec5f1dc58757ad6cffdacedb1a58854a600312cc82c494d2c55856f1e25c06b4b6fcee5ddabebfe2d30057589a86e9750b459e9d60598cc6e5c52a4697030b2b8921f29f#). My script below can parse the links of next pages until 10. However, I can't go past that link visible as 10 at the bottom of that page.

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

base = 'https://www.icab.es'
link = 'https://www.icab.es/?go=eaf9d1a0ec5f1dc58757ad6cffdacedb1a58854a600312cc82c494d2c55856f1e25c06b4b6fcee5ddabebfe2d30057589a86e9750b459e9d60598cc6e5c52a4697030b2b8921f29f'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
    p = 1
    while True:
        r = s.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
        """some data I can fetch myself from current pages, so ignore this portion"""

        p+=1
        next_page = soup.select_one(f"a[title='{p}']")
        if next_page:
            link = urljoin(base,next_page.get("href"))
            print("next page:",link)
        else:
            break
```

***How can I get all the next page links from the website above?***

PS selenium is not an option I would like to cope with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to get the `href` of `">"`  when your `(p-1)%10 != 0`

[image]

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

base = 'https://www.icab.es'
link = 'https://www.icab.es/?go=eaf9d1a0ec5f1dc58757ad6cffdacedb1a58854a600312cc82c494d2c55856f1e25c06b4b6fcee5ddabebfe2d30057589a86e9750b459e9d60598cc6e5c52a4697030b2b8921f29f'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
    p = 1
    while True:
        r = s.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
        """some data I can fetch myself from current pages, so ignore this portion"""

        p += 1

        if not ((p-1) % 10):
            next_page = soup.select_one(f"a[title='Següent']")
        else:
            next_page = soup.select_one(f"a[title='{p}']")

        if next_page:
            link = urljoin(base, next_page.get("href"))
            print("page", next_page.text, link)
```

Result(`page >>` could be considered as `page ?1`):

```
D:\python37\python.exe E:/work/Compile/python/python_project/try.py
page 2 https://www.icab.es/?go=eaf9d1a0ec5f1dc58757ad6cffdacedb1a58854a600312cc7aa5373444141c64ddd1e9bee4bbc2e02ab2de1dfe88d7a8623a04a8617c3a28f3f17b03d0448cd1d399689a629d00f53e570c691ad10f5cfba28f6f9ee8d48ddb9b701d116d7c2a6d4ea403cef5d996fcb28a12b9f7778cd7521cfdf3d243cb2b1f3de9dfe304a10437e417f6c68df79efddd721f2ab8167085132c5e745958a3a859b9d9f04b63e402ec6e8ae29bee9f4791fed51e5758ae33460e9a12b6d73f791fd118c0c95180539f1db11c86a7ab97b31f94fb84334dce6867d519873cc3b80e182ff0b778
page 3 https://www.icab.es/?go=eaf9d1a0ec5f1dc58757ad6cffdacedb1a58854a600312cc7aa5373444141c64cc111efb5ef5c42ecde14350e1f5a2e0e8db36a9258d5c95496c2450f44ccd8c4074edb392b09c03e136988ff15e707fa0e01d1ee6c3198a166e2677b4b418e0b07cafd4d98a19364077e7ed2ea0341001481d8b9622a969a524a487e7d69f6b571f2cb03c2277ecd858c68a7848a0995c1c0e873d705a72661b69ab39b253bb775bc6f7f6ae3df2028114735a04dcb8043775e73420cb40c4a5eccb727438ea225b582830ce84eb959753ded1b3eb57a14b283c282caa7ad04626be8320b4ab
page 4 https://www.icab.es/?go=eaf9d1a0ec5f1dc58757ad6cffdacedb1a58854a600312cc7aa5373444141c64d8e9a9d04523d43bfb106098548163bfec74e190632187d135f2a0949b334acad719ad7c326481a43dfc6f966eb038e0a5a178968601ad0681d586ffc8ec21e414628f96755116e65b7962dfcf3a227fc1053d17701937d4f747b94c273ce8b9ccec178386585075c17a4cb483c45b85c1209329d1251767b8a0b4fa29969cf6ad42c7b04fcc1e64b9defd528753677f56e081e75c1cbc81d1f4cc93adbde29d06388474671abbab246160d0b3f03a17d1db2c6cd6c6d7a243d872e353200a35
page 5 https://www.icab.es/?go=eaf9d1a0ec5f1dc58757ad6cffdacedb1a58854a600312cc7aa5373444141c643ba4bcf6634af323cf239c7ccf7eca827c3a245352a03532a91c0ced15db81dcfc52b6dfa69853a68cb320e29ca25e25fac3da0e85667145375c3fa1541d80b1b056c03c02400220223ad5766bd1a4824171188fd85a5412b59bd48fe604451cbd56d763be67b50e474befa78340d625d222f1bb6b337d8d2b335d1aa7d0374b1be2372e77948f22a073e5e8153c32202a219ed2ef3f695b5b0040ded1ca9c4a03462b5937182c004a1a425725d3d20a10b41fd215d551abf10ef5e8a76ace4f
page 6 https://www.icab.es/?go=eaf9d1a0ec5f1dc58757ad6cffdacedb1a58854a600312cc7aa5373444141c64418cdf5c38c01a1ac019cc46242eb9ba25f012f2e4bee18a2864a19dde58d6ee2ae93254aff239c70b7019526af1a435e0e89a7c81dc4842e365163d8f9e571ae4fc8b0fc7455f573abee020e21207a604f3d6b7c2015c300a7b1dbc75980b435bb1904535bed2610771fee5e3338a79fad6d024ec2684561c3376463b2cacc00a99659918b41a12c92233bca3eaa1e003dbb0a094b787244ef3c33688b4382f89ad64a92fa8b738dd810b6e32a087564a8db2422c5b2013e9103b1b57b4248d
page 7 https://www.icab.es/?go=eaf9d1a0ec5f1dc58757ad6cffdacedb1a58854a600312cc7aa5373444141c64f96d66b04d442c09e3b891f2a5f3fb235c1aa2786face046665066db9a63e7ca4523e5cf28f4f17898204642a7d5ef3f8474ecd5bf58b252944d148467b495ad2450ea157ce8f606d4b9a6bc2ac04bec3a666757eac42cbea0737e8191b0d375425e11c76990c82246cfb9cbe94daa46942d824ff9f144f6b51c768b50c3e35acfa81e5ebf95bcb5200f5b505595908907c99b8d59893724eb16d5694d36cd30d8a15744af616675b2d6a447c10b79ca04814aece8c7ab4d878b7955cd5cd9ef
page 8 https://www.icab.es/?go=eaf9d1a0ec5f1dc58757ad6cffdacedb1a58854a600312cc7aa5373444141c64d1c210208efbd4630d44a5a92d37e5eabccba6abf83c2584404a24d08e0ad738be3598a03bbec8975275b06378cc5f7c55a9b700eb5bd4ee243a3c30f781512c0ebd23800890cb150621caab21a7a879639331b369d92bb9668815465f5d3b6c061daa011784909fc09af75ab705612ba504b4c268b43f8a029e840b8c69531423e8b5e8fe91d7cc628c309ffb633e233932b7c1b57c5cf0a2f2f47618bca4837ce355f34ae154565b447cfffcecb66458d19e5e5f3547f6916cd1c30baec1a7
page 9 https://www.icab.es/?go=eaf9d1a0ec5f1dc58757ad6cffdacedb1a58854a600312cc7aa5373444141c6415c187c4ac2cf9d4c982984e1b56faf34a31272a90b11557d1651ad92b01a2ecd3c719cfe78863f99e31b0fc1b6bc7b09e1e0e585ebdc0b04fc9dca8744bb66e8af86d65b39827f1265a82aea0286376456ccfa9cce638d72c494db2391127979eed3d349d725f2e60e2629512c388738fc26b1c9f16a2b478862469835474b305f1300c0aa53c2c4033e4b0967a542079915e30bb18418eb79a47a292ed835dd54689c1fd9ceda898678e7114fa95d559b55367e6f7f9d1ce3fb5ebb5d479c5
page 10 https://www.icab.es/?go=eaf9d1a0ec5f1dc58757ad6cffdacedb1a58854a600312cc7aa5373444141c644ab59a0b943deffee8845c2521afef0ea3ff2d96cc2b65a071da1201603b54b15b5c4363e92285c60dffd0e893ba6a58ff528fb3278db8e746697dc8712936a560a3da8085e3dcab05949afecddaced326332986240624575c6b7f104182a8c57718ec62e728d8eaa886a611ad55e0d3dd0c1ba59b47cf89d1bd5b000f9fbc5bd7d6310742a53eedfa44383d62145c28ebcf9f180ca49a3616fcfaf7ecaaa0b2f7183fc1d10d18e0062613e73f9077d11a1dfaf044990c200ac10aac4f7cb332
page » https://www.icab.es/?go=eaf9d1a0ec5f1dc58757ad6cffdacedb1a58854a600312cc7aa5373444141c64ff2c69157ff5cf4b8ccbc2674205f4fb3048dc10db0c7cb36c42fbc59aaa972b9fab70578ff58757fae7a1f1ca17076dfddb919cf92389ba66c8de7f6ea9ec08277b0228f8bd14ea82409ff7e5a051ea58940736b475c6f75c7eba096b711812ed5b6b8454ec11145b0ce10191a38068c6ca7e7c64a86b4c71819d55b3ab34233e9887c7bfa05f9f8bc488cb0986fb2680b8cb9278a437e7c91c7b9d15426e159c30c6c2351ed300925ef1b24bbf2dbf60cf9dea935d179235ed46640d2b0b54
page 12 https://www.icab.es/?go=eaf9d1a0ec5f1dc58757ad6cffdacedb1a58854a600312cc7aa5373444141c64346907383e54eae9d772c10d3600822205ff9b81665ff0f58fd876b4e0d9aeb6e0271904c5251d9cf6eb1fdd1ea16f8ea3f42ad3db66678bc538c444e0e5e4064946826aaf85746b3f87fb436d83a8eb6d6590c25dc7f208a16c1db7307921d79269591e036fed1ec78ec7351227f925a32d4d08442b9fd65b02f6ef247ca5f713e4faffe994bf26a14c2cb21268737bc2bc92bb41b3e3aaa05de10da4e38de3ab725adb5560eee7575cdf6d51d59870efacc1b9553609ae1e16ea25e6d6e9e6
page 13 https://www.icab.es/?go=eaf9d1a0ec5f1dc58757ad6cffdacedb1a58854a600312cc7aa5373444141c64afc9149ba3dadd6054f6d8629d1c750431a15f9c4048195cfc2823f61f6cfd1f2e4f78eb835829db8e7c88279bf3a38788d8feaf5327f1b42d863bba24d893ea5e033510dc2e0579474ac7efcc1915438eacb83f2a3b5416e64e3beb726d721eb79f55082be0371414ccd132e95cd53339cf7a8d6ec15b72595bf87107d082c9db7bba6cf45b8cfe7a9352abe2f289ae8591afcfd78e17486c25e94ea57c00e290613a18a8b991def7e1cd4cae517a4ee1b744036336fbc68b657cd33cc4c949
```

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with SSL, so I changed the default ssl_context for this site:

```
import ssl
import requests
import requests.adapters
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981429/ssl-failure-on-windows-using-python-requests/50215614
class SSLContextAdapter(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
        # Sets up old and insecure TLSv1.
        ssl_context.options &= ~ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_3 & ~ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_2 & ~ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1
        ssl_context.minimum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1
        kwargs['ssl_context'] = ssl_context
        return super(SSLContextAdapter, self).init_poolmanager(*args, **kwargs)


base = 'https://www.icab.es'
link = 'https://www.icab.es/?go=eaf9d1a0ec5f1dc58757ad6cffdacedb1a58854a600312cc82c494d2c55856f1e25c06b4b6fcee5ddabebfe2d30057589a86e9750b459e9d60598cc6e5c52a4697030b2b8921f29f'

with requests.session() as s:
    s.mount('https://www.icab.es', SSLContextAdapter())

    p = 1
    while True:
        print('Page {}..'.format(p))
        # r = urllib.request.urlopen(link, context=ssl_context)
        r = s.get(link)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

        for li in soup.select('li.principal'):
            print(li.get_text(strip=True))

        p += 1
        link = soup.select_one('a[title="{}"]'.format(p))
        if not link:
            link = soup.select_one('a[title="Següent"]')
            if not link:
                break
        link = base + link['href']
```

Prints:

```
Page 1..
Sr./Sra. Martínez Gòmez, Marc
Sr./Sra. Eguinoa de San Roman, Roman
Sr./Sra. Morales Santiago, Maria Victoria
Sr./Sra. Bengoa Tortajada, Javier
Sr./Sra. Moralo Rodríguez, Xavier
Sr./Sra. Romagosa Huerta, Marta
Sr./Sra. Peña Moncho, Juan
Sr./Sra. Piñana Morera, Roman
Sr./Sra. Millán Sánchez, Antonio
Sr./Sra. Martínez Mira, Manel
Sr./Sra. Montserrat Rincón, Anna
Sr./Sra. Fernández Paricio, Maria Teresa
Sr./Sra. Ruiz Macián- Dagnino, Claudia
Sr./Sra. Barba Ausejo, Pablo
Sr./Sra. Bruna de Quixano, Jose Luis
Sr./Sra. Folch Estrada, Fernando
Sr./Sra. Gracia Castellón, Sonia
Sr./Sra. Sales Valls, Gemma Elena
Sr./Sra. Pastor Giménez-Salinas, Adolfo
Sr./Sra. Font Jané, Àlvar
Sr./Sra. García González, Susana
Sr./Sra. Garcia-Tornel Florensa, Xavier
Sr./Sra. Marín Granados, Alejandra
Sr./Sra. Albero Jové, José María
Sr./Sra. Galcerà Margalef, Montserrat
Page 2..
Sr./Sra. Chimenos Minguella, Sergi
Sr./Sra. Lacasta Casado, Ramón
Sr./Sra. Alcay Morandeira, Carlos
Sr./Sra. Ribó Massó, Ignacio
Sr./Sra. Fitó Baucells, Antoni
Sr./Sra. Paredes Batalla, Patricia
Sr./Sra. Prats Viñas, Francesc
Sr./Sra. Correig Ferré, Gerard
Sr./Sra. Subirana Freixas, Alba
Sr./Sra. Álvarez Crexells, Juan
Sr./Sra. Glaser Woloschin, Joan Nicolás
Sr./Sra. Nel-lo Padro, Francesc Xavier
Sr./Sra. Oliveras Dalmau, Rosa Maria
Sr./Sra. Badia Piqué, Montserrat
Sr./Sra. Fuentes-Lojo Rius, Alejandro
Sr./Sra. Argemí Delpuy, Marc
Sr./Sra. Espinoza Carrizosa, Pina
Sr./Sra. Ges Clot, Carla
Sr./Sra. Antón Tuneu, Beatriz
Sr./Sra. Schroder Vilalta, Andrea
Sr./Sra. Belibov, Mariana
Sr./Sra. Sole Lopez, Silvia
Sr./Sra. Reina Pardo, Luis
Sr./Sra. Cardenal Lagos, Manel Josep
Sr./Sra. Bru Galiana, David


...and so on.
```

Comment: I usually prefer to go for your solution @Andrej Kesely but this time jizhihaoSAMA came up with his solution first. Thanks.